# DocuSign from php

Tags: php, docusignapi

From a PHP appliation I am trying to Sign a document using Docusign REST API. The steps like:

1. Send the document in Docusign for eSign
2. Sign the Document
3. Send to recipient and download the signed document

I can able to push the document. But how it can be signed from inside from my application and send to recipient.

Any help will appreciated.

I am using REST API to do the above job

Any API link or any guidance

Answer (score 0):

An example using the DocuSign PHP library is available here: https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant

Specifically, if you want to have the signing take place in your application, you're looking for example 1: Embedded Signing Ceremony